# multiple setInterval for different elements on single page

Tags: javascript

i have different span elements. each of those elements displays a value, which is determined by a refresh() method. now i want to refresh the values of each element by using setInterval method of javascript. i have tried the following code:

```
            var i = 0;
            var refresher = new Array();
            for(i=0;i<=no_of_times;i++){
                $("#main").append('<tr>');
                $("#main").append('<td>Value: <b><span id="id'+i+'"></span></b></td>');
                refresh("key", i);  //for first values
                refresher[i] = setInterval("refresh(configJSON.users[i].key, i)",30000);
            }
            $("#main").append('</table>');
        }
```

the value is displayed the first time, though it is not refreshed after 30s. what may be the reason for that

Comment: Maybe the value isnt changed even after 30s. Maybe.

Comment: is the approach correct? because value definitely changes after 30s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like that;

```
    function f(key, i) {
        refresh(key, i);
        setTimeout(function() {
            f(key, i);
        }, 30000);
    }
    var i = 0;
    var refresher = new Array();
    for(i=0;i<=no_of_times;i++){
        $("#main").append('<tr>');
        $("#main").append('<td>Value: <b><span id="id'+i+'"></span></b></td>');
        f(key, i);
    }
    $("#main").append('</table>');
```

In this way every 30 seconds the refresh will be done.

Comment: refresh is occuring. but its not at 30s. also, can the refresh interval be customized ?

Comment: to be precise, it refreshes after 45s

Comment: i fix my code, i forgot to set timeOut value...
        setTimeout(function() {
            f(key, i);
        }, 30000);